# How to achieve thread-safety for my Java YAML-API?

Tags: java, multithreading, yaml, thread-safety

The example yaml file: `example.yml` is represented as a `DreamYaml` object.
That file is loaded and parsed, at initialization.

Now let's imagine multiple threads are loading, editing and saving that file at the same time. So that multiple `DreamYaml` objects get created for the same file. What is the best way of achieving thread safety in this scenario?

My idea was calling a static synchronized `lockFile()` method inside of the `load()` method and `unlockFile()` inside of the `save()` method. The problem with this is, that you would have to call `save()` at the end every time for the file to unlock and also this could block the file for other threads for a lot longer than actually needed.

I guess the best way would be calling the `lockFile()` method inside of `save()`, then inside of that locked section, `load()` the file again so that the current objects in-memory values get updated and match the actual/'real' current values. Then simply `save()` the file and release the lock. In this case, I would have to make sure, that the recent in-memory changes made to the values are not overwritten from the `load()` call. I don't think there are any more major drawbacks to this approach. *Edit: I just found out that the major drawback of this approach is that its not actually thread safe. thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68313798/13600212

**Edit: This is what I came up with:

```java
    /**
     * If you access the same yaml file from multiple threads, its recommended to lock the file before loading it. <br>
     * Remember to {@link #unlockFile()} so that other threads can work with the file too. <br>
     * If you don't do that, other threads will stay stuck at {@link #lockFile()} forever. <br>
     * Example: <br>
     * <pre>
     *     DreamYaml yaml = new DreamYaml("example.yml");
     *     yaml.lockFile();
     *     yaml.load();
     *     // Do changes to file here
     *     yaml.save();
     *     yaml.unlockFile();
     * </pre>
     */
    public synchronized void lockFile(){
        if (file!=null){
            ReentrantLock lock = null;
            synchronized (pathsAndLocks){
                if (pathsAndLocks.containsKey(file.getAbsolutePath()))
                    lock = pathsAndLocks.get(file.getAbsolutePath()); // If another thread has already the locked, the current thread will wait until it gets unlocked
                else{
                    lock = new ReentrantLock();
                    pathsAndLocks.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), lock);
                }
            }
            lock.lock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * If you access the same yaml file from multiple threads, its recommended to lock the file before loading it. <br>
     * Remember to {@link #unlockFile()} so that other threads can work with the file too. <br>
     * If you don't do that, other threads will stay stuck at {@link #lockFile()} forever. <br>
     * Example: <br>
     * <pre>
     *     DreamYaml yaml = new DreamYaml("example.yml");
     *     yaml.lockFile();
     *     yaml.load();
     *     // Do changes to file here
     *     yaml.save();
     *     yaml.unlockFile();
     * </pre>
     */
    public synchronized void unlockFile(){
        if (file!=null){
            ReentrantLock lock = null;
            synchronized (pathsAndLocks){
                if (pathsAndLocks.containsKey(file.getAbsolutePath())){
                    lock = pathsAndLocks.get(file.getAbsolutePath()); // If another thread has already the locked, the current thread will wait until it gets unlocked
                    lock.unlock();
                    if(!lock.hasQueuedThreads())
                        pathsAndLocks.remove(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the code above the `pathsAndLocks` variable is a hashmap containing the yaml files paths and their locks. That means that there is one ReentrantLock per file. Now the users can call `lockFile()` before loading the yaml file to achieve thread safety and `unlockFile()` when they are done.

But I am not entirely sure... so what do you think about this?

Further details about my Java-YAML API: https://github.com/Osiris-Team/Dream-Yaml

Comment: Why are you trying to allow simultaneous editing of an on-disk file—what feature are you providing?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- It's for another project of mine, where I have to access a single file from multiple threads and make changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking the data only when saving is not thread-safe.

Assume some item in the data holds the value `0`. Two threads concurrently want to increase the value by 1. The following classical race condition can occur:

Both threads read in `0` concurrently. Both calculate the new value to be `1`. One thread acquires the lock, loads current data, sets the item to `1`, saves. Other thread then acquires the lock, loads the updated data, replaces the item with `1` *because the new value has already been calculated*, then saves. Result is the the item in the file is `1` when it should be `2`.

Regardless of whether you save a value to a file or keep it in memory, to achieve thread safety, you do need an exclusive lock (or an equivalent mechanism) in place from the time you read the value to the time you commit the updated value.

The question of what is the *best* way to achieve thread safety cannot be answered generally. It depends on your use-case and may need extensive analysis of the behavior of your system. As already mentioned, an exclusive lock from load to save will work (does not detect external modification of the file of course).

It is unclear why you want to save and load the data all the time, it seems far simpler to load the file once on startup and keep it in memory. When you make modifications, you save the file but keep it in memory. This would only be bad if the file is a) large and b) modifications happen only sparsely.

Comment: Yeah I guess u'r right, but is there any alternative you would suggest, because locking from start to finish isn't the best solution.

Comment: I guess the best way is really locking from start to finish. I guess I'll add the `lockFile()` and `unlockFile()` methods to my API, so that the user can decide whether to use them to achieve thread safety or not. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @OsirisTeam If you hold the file data in memory, your lock time decreases drastically since you do not need to read the file every time. You can offload writing the file into a dedicated thread and have a `commit()` function that releases the lock, commands that thread to save and immediately returns. It is possible to allow a thread to acquire the lock on the data while the file is being written, as long as you write in a temp file and rename it afterwards *only if* the saving thread sees that no modifications have been made while it saved the file (otherwise another `commit()` will come).

Comment: I just updated the question with the new approach. What do you think?

Comment: @OsirisTeam Mind that this is not [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) and you should ask there if you do not have a specific problem. In any case, a `synchronized` block inside a `synchronized` method is a code smell since nested locking is prone to deadlocks. It seems your code would be a lot cleaner if you had a singleton file handle for each file, e.g. `DreamYaml.handle("example.yml");` returns the single handle to `example.yml` and creates it if it doesn't exist, and then with `load` you both lock it and return an object holding the values.